# How to sync time between Windows and OS X?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, windows, bootcamp

I'm using OS X Mountain Lion with Windows 8 installed via Boot Camp. When I switch between Windows and OS X the time in each operative system is different, exist a difference approximately of 4 hours with the same Time Zone.

So, I need to change the time when start Windows or OS X, but automatically change the time of the other operative system.

Exist any trick that solved this issue using the same Time Zone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is to set Windows to use UTC, I didn't test with Windows 8 but I think will work.

Start with Windows and create a new file with the name `setUTC.reg` and paste this text inside:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
"RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
```

save and close, after double click to add the value to the windows registry.
Restart Windows and set the time, after the time zone will not change anymore.

Answer (score -1):

A one click solution for this:

http://romascusoftware.com/windows-mac-time-fix/

I found this solution to be the most convenient, other solutions involve modifying the registry on the windows side or running some commands on the terminal on the mac side.